# Sophos Home Premium blocks Vaadin XHR Requests

Tags: vaadin

We host a Vaadin application on a Tomcat webserver. Users using Sophos Home Premium have issues connecting to our page. The Chrome and Firefox developer console shows that some(not all) XHR Requests get stalled immediately and afterward fail due to a timeout. As a result, the Browser shows a message that the server is offline. The Sophos Home Web Interface shows no messages in the history overview. Adding our site to the excluded pages didn't change anything. As soon as we deactivate the Web Protection, everything works fine. I attached a screenshot from the Chrome developer console that shows the issue.
I would appreciate some help solving this problem.

Vaadin 23.3.10
Tomcat 9.0.63

[Google developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiQvh.png)

Comment: You will have investigate on Sophos side, seems they block too much for no apparent reason

Comment: I have also contacted Sophos support. What I find weird is that several XHR requests are sent simultaneously when navigating. The first one seems to work, and the second one is blocked. I compared it with the Vaadin Online Demo (https://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!dashboard) and could not reproduce this behavior. That's why I assumed it could also be due to a Vaadin setting.